# Any guide out there that shows new comers to rails how to build a social netoworking website with rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of a guide or set of guides (like screen casts) which shows a new comer to rails how to build a social networking website with rails 3? I know of RailSpace, but the only problem is the book is outdated as it uses rails 2 (I believe).

I'm trying to learn Rails 3, and the way I want to learn it is by practicing to build a lean version of facebook with rails 3.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://railsforzombies.org/. It's a set of video tutorials and exercises that take you through building a "Twitter for Zombies". It's also free.

Comment: [Rails Tutorial by Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) is great also. Free unless you feel the need to purchase the videos.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book.  It's written by Michael Hartl who won a Ruby Hero Award at RailsConf 2011.  It's quite exhaustive and demonstrates many good practices.